# how can i get 64 bit ubuntu/debian to recognise both usb2 and usb3 ports on my gigabyte ga 970a-d3p motherboard

Tags: usb, 64-bit

i've tried several suggested solutions none of which work. previous 32 bit ubuntus saw all the ports on my motherboard but no 64 bit ubuntu/debian versions have been able to utilize all the ports.  the 4 usb3 ports work but not the 10 usb10 ports.  the suggestion to turn iommu on in the bios causes a crash with loss of data.  both the bios and windows 10 can use all the ports.

```
lsusb -t
/:  Bus 09.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 5000M
    |__ Port 3: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=uas, 5000M
/:  Bus 08.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/1p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=, 480M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 3, If 1, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=snd-ua101, 480M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 3, If 2, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=snd-ua101, 480M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 3, If 3, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=snd-ua101, 480M
        |__ Port 2: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
        |__ Port 4: Dev 5, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
        |__ Port 4: Dev 5, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
/:  Bus 07.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ohci-pci/4p, 12M
/:  Bus 06.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ohci-pci/2p, 12M
/:  Bus 05.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ohci-pci/5p, 12M
/:  Bus 04.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ohci-pci/5p, 12M
/:  Bus 03.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/4p, 480M
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/5p, 480M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/5p, 480M
sid@sid:~$
```

Comment: Can you [edit] to add the output of `lsusb -t` to your question?

Comment: Please provide some clear Ubuntu product/release details; I'd expect the same results for a 64bit and 32bit release where they are the same release + same kernel stack, but you've given no details. Also please don't hide details in title (*which may not be viewable if using smaller screens/larger fonts*) putting all details in your question.